# Capitalizing the first letter of a string only

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have already taken a look at such posts like:

[Format to first letter uppercase](http://forums.asp.net/t/1040231.aspx?Format%20to%20first%20letter%20upper%20case) 
[How to capitalise the first letter of every word in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906769/how-to-capitalise-the-first-letter-of-every-word-in-a-string)

But none of these seem to actually work. I would have thought to start with that there would just be a:

```
.Capitalize();
```

Like there is:

```
.Lower(); & .Upper();
```

Are there any documentation or references regarding converting to a string like the following?

```
string before = "INVOICE";
```

To then becoming:

```
string after = "Invoice";
```

I receive no errors using the way the posts solutions I read give me, however, the `before` still remains capitalized.

Comment: You can create a function that takes a string as input, takes the first character as a substring, makes that uppercase, replaces the first character with the uppercase version and returns the result.

Comment: And second question you need to read is [Convert all first letter to upper case, rest lower for each word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943273/convert-all-first-letter-to-upper-case-rest-lower-for-each-word?lq=1)

Comment: `s = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(s.toLower());` from the so called duplicate is the link I provided in the question which I stated 'DID NOT WORK' so unmark duplicate, thanks... @SergeyBerezovskiy

Comment: @KyleE4K 'DID NOT WORK` is not explanation of problem. Question is already answered and it has WORKING solution. Read both links carefully

Comment: So you have just admitted it isn't a duplicate, you're now saying the question does not state an explanation of the issue... make up your mind @SergeyBerezovskiy

Comment: @KyleE4K you marked copy of solution I linked as correct answer. So it **is** duplicate as I thought. And you should go and read [How to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I'm pretty sure that you thought strings are mutable in .net

Comment: You changed the duplicate link, so lets not pretend

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What about using `ToUpper` on the first char and `ToLower` on the remaining string?

```
string after = char.ToUpper(before.First()) + before.Substring(1).ToLower();
```

Comment: `string trantype = char.ToUpper(row.Trantype[0]) + row.Trantype.SubString(1).ToLower();` - Returns this error:  'string' does not contain a definition for 'SubString' and no extension method 'SubString' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: There is a typo: `SubString` is called `Substring`.

Comment: If you remove the `]` after the `.First()` it works :) Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Sorry.

Answer (score 12):

You can create a method that does something like this:

```
string UppercaseFirst(string str)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        return string.Empty;
    return char.ToUpper(str[0]) + str.Substring(1).ToLower();
}
```

And use it like this:

```
string str = "thISstringLOokSHorribLE";
string upstr = UppercaseFirst(str);
```

to get this:

```
Thisstringlookshorrible
```